# Web Api attribute route not working

Tags: c#, web-services, routes

I have a web api using the owin pipeline. I am only using attribute routing. I have 3 controllers with a few routes on each. All the routes work sans one.

## ContactsController

```
[RoutePrefix("accounts/{accountNumber}/contacts")]
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [Route("{contactId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetContactsAsync(
        string accountNumber, 
        int? contactId = null);

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{contactId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateContactsAsync(
        [FromBody] UpdateContactsRequest request,
        string accountNumber,
        int contactId)
}
```

GET: `http://localhost/accounts/1/contacts` -- Works
GET: `http://localhost/accounts/1/contacts/1` -- Works
PUT: `http://localhost/accounts/1/contacts/1` -- DOESN'T WORK

I get a 404 on the PUT. It doesn't find the route.

I've also tried the following routes on my PUT:

```
[Route("/accounts/{accountNumber}/contacts/{contactId}")]
[Route("~/accounts/{accountNumber}/contacts/{contactId}")]
```

And I've tried rearranging the parameters in various ways as well.

**UPDATE 1: Postman call**
[image: postman]

**UPDATE 2: Request object**

```
public class UpdateContactsRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string AlternatePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you making the PUT request?  Have you considered Swagger which is excellent for WebAPI documentation and testing

Comment: I'm using postman. Swagger doesn't work out of the box with owin so i haven't bothered with it yet. By swagger i mean swashbuckle...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the postman request you are making

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately I wont be able to get to it until Monday...

Comment: i added the postman call

Comment: Ok can you also post the request C# class? Snd have you annotated it with JSONProperty

Comment: It's not the body that's the issue. If I comment out the [FromBody] Parameter so it just accepts `accountNumber` and `contactId` I still get a 404.

Comment: And I get the 404 instantly too, when I send the request. Not sure if that's helpful.

Comment: I've even tried commenting out the get request to see if it's route was interfering for some reason. Nope. Still 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a web.config configuration issue.

I was missing a system.webServer config section. I added that section with the following copied from another web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Now all is well, and it finds my PUT route.